# Почему не срабатывает preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

Есть html форма в которой пользователь может менять свои данные:

```html
 <form action='/user/editProfile' id="edit-profile_form" method="post">
<ul class='profile-data'>
    <li class='profile-data_item persona-icon'>Никнейм: <input id='profile_nickname' name='nickname' type="text" placeholder="Никнейм:" value="{{myNickname}}"   :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false"></li>
    <li class='profile-data_item'>Имя: <input name='name' id='profile_name' type="text" placeholder="Имя:" value="{{myName}}"  :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false"></li>
    <li class='profile-data_item'>Фамилия: <input name='surname' id='profile_surname' type="text" placeholder="Фамилия:" value="{{mySurname}}"  :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false"></li>
    <li class='profile-data_item b-day-icon'>Возраст: <input name='age' id='profile_age' type="text" placeholder="Возраст:" value="{{myAge}}"  :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false"></li>
    <li class='profile-data_item place-icon'><input type="text" name='city' id='profile_city' placeholder="Город" value="{{myCity}}"  :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false">, <input name='country' id='profile_country' type="text" placeholder="Страна" value="{{myCountry}}"  :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false"></li>
    <li class='profile-data_item phone-icon'>Телефон: <input name='phoneNumber' id='profile_phoneNumber' type="text" placeholder="Телефон:" value="{{myPhoneNumber}}"  :readonly="inputStatus == 1 ? true : false"></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value='{{csrfToken}}' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="edit-profile_submit">
</ul>
</form>
```

И jquery/ajax код, который должен отправлять данные на сервер.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var csrf_token = {{csrfToken}};

        $("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
            if (s.type == "POST") {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
            }
        });

        var pathname = window.location.href;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/user/editProfile',
            data: {
                name: $("#profile_name").val(),
                nickname: $("#profile_nickname").val(),
                surname: $("#profile_surname").val(),
                country: $("#profile_country").val(),
                city: $("#profile_city").val(),
                phoneNumber: $("#profile_phoneNumber").val(),
                age: $("#profile_age").val()
            },
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/html, charset: UTF-*",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
```

Но по неизвестным причинам, при нажатии на submit, сайт переходит по ссылке, которая указана в action=''. Почему-то preventDefault не делает то, что должен. В чём проблема? Версия jquery 3.1.0, на сервере форму обрабатывает код...

```
router.post('/editProfile', isLoggedIn, function (req, res, next){
    var id = req.user._id;
    console.log(req.body);
    var nickname = req.body.nickname;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var surname = req.body.surname;
    var age = req.body.age;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var country = req.body.country;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $set: { nickname: nickname, name: name, surname: surname, age: age, city: city, country: country, phoneNumber: phoneNumber }}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log("ADDED!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    });
});
```

В итоге форма отправляется и в базу заносятся новые данные, но страница перезагружается, хотя мне это не нужно.
Все действия происходят на странице /user/:userid

Comment: $("form").submit(function(e) { your code.... и в самом низу return false;})

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil где именно?

Comment: вставьте `alert("submit");` перед `e.preventDefault();`. Скорее всего, обработчик не навешивается на элемент формы.

Comment: @SultanovShamil, `return false` в данном случае не обязателен

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если так вышло, что `preventDefault` не прервал отправки данных на сервер через `submit`, то можно добавить дополнительную проверку:

```
e.preventDefault();
if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

Также, чтобы отправки формы не произошло -  достаточно внутри обработчика, точнее внутри функции, в конце, написать `return false;`. Если функция возвращает `false`, то отправки не будет, а если `true` - выполниться отправка формы.

`preventDefault` может не срабатывать по причине того, что имеются другие обработчики, которые отправляют данные с формы, к примеру. Для такого случая можно попробовать вызвать [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation), а не `preventDefault`. То есть так:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // вместо e.preventDefault();
```

---

Ну а вообще, вот этот код:

```
$("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
if (s.type == "POST") {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
    }
});
```

Вы в [`bind`](http://jquerybook.ru/api/.bind()-fn27.html) к `"body"` устанавливаете обработчик события на [`ajaxSend`](http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=3), который срабатывает каждый раз перед отправкой Ajax-запроса, причем [`setRequestHeader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) -  устанавливает значение заголовка запроса `HTTP`. Проблема кроется скорее всего тут и `preventDefault` срабатывает, но срабатывает уже другой обработчик, после `preventDefault`. Ну и проблемная строка кода вот эта:

```
var csrf_token = {{csrfToken}};
```

Answer (score 2):

Что приходит в браузер вместо вот этой строки?

```
var csrf_token = {{csrfToken}};
```

Вероятно, Вам нужно:

```
var csrf_token = "{{csrfToken}}";
```

Answer (score 2):

1. У вас в форме уже есть скрытый input _csrf, зачем отправлять повторно в заголовке?
2. csrf лучше хранить в подобном виде:

   ```
   <meta name="csrf" content="{{csrfToken}}">
   ```

   и брать его как-нибудь так:

   ```
   var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   ```
3. Смените:

   ```
   data: {
       name: $("#profile_name").val(),
       nickname: $("#profile_nickname").val(),
       surname: $("#profile_surname").val(),
       country: $("#profile_country").val(),
       city: $("#profile_city").val(),
       phoneNumber: $("#profile_phoneNumber").val(),
       age: $("#profile_age").val()
   },
   ```

   На:

   ```
   var toSend = $(this).serializeArray(); // перед вызовом ajax, здесь будут все ваши данные с формы, с абсолютно такими же значениями

   $.ajax({
   // ...
       data: toSend,
   // ...
   });
   ```
4. У меня данный код сработал, но, я так понмаю, что вы используете blade и скорее всего проблема в этой строчке:

   ```
    var csrf_token = {{csrfToken}};
   ```

   Попробуйте сменить на:

   ```
    var csrf_token = '{{csrfToken}}';
   ```

Comment: В подобном виде: <meta name="csrf" content="{{csrfToken}}"> Не могу мету в редактор добавить :)